# Relative directory path GNU make

Tags: gnu-make, relative-path

I have defined a source.mk with include path at make for header files. I have to give the absolute file path to INCLUDES or an error of file not found appear.

```
# Add your include paths to this variable


INCLUDES =    -I/home/ecee/C1M1-Abubaker/include/common    \
```

my make file is in :

```
~/home/ecee/C1M1-Abubaker/
```

and the header file need to be included in :

```
~/home/ecee/C1M1-Abubaker/include/common
```

The question is how to find a path dynamically from another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for file in a directory above you can use `-I./include/common`and for two directories above: `-I../include/common`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`realpath` make function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-realpath):

> `$(realpath names…)`
>
> For each file name in names return the canonical absolute name. A canonical name does not contain any `.` or `..` components, nor any repeated path separators (`/`) or symlinks. In case of a failure the empty string is returned. Consult the `realpath(3)` documentation for a list of possible failure causes.

In your case, that would probably be `$(realpath include/common)`.

Comment: you mean I should use  `INCLUDES =    -I/$(realpath common)`?
This didn't work either. I am a newbie in Linux

Comment: You need to specify the full relative path, so `include/common`.

Comment: I used it and didn't work `INCLUDES =    -I/$(realpath include/common) `

Comment: I tried to use `$(CURDIR)` but it gives me the directory where the make file is, not the the header file that I want to include. If there any function that could delete the last directory from the current directory function, it may work.

Comment: @Ashraf No. Actually `${CURDIR}` gives you the current working folder of the _make_ process. The makefile can be in another folder!

Comment: @Ashraf As @Florian says, all the compiler needs to see is a simple `-Iinclude/common`. To achieve this in the makefile, you simply write `$(addprefix -I,${INCLUDES})`. First, `${INCLUDES}` becomes `include/common` (say) leaving _make_ with `$(addprefix -I,include/common)`. This is further expanded leaving you with `-Iinclude/common`. Job done.

Answer (score 1):

The OP said

> … or an error of file not found appear

Something like:

```
mustexist = $(or $(realpath $1),$(error Path [$1] does not exist!))

1.o: 1.cpp
    gcc -I$(call mustexist,${INCLUDES}) $< -o $@
```

If `$(realpath …)` expands to nothing (the path does not exist),
then *make* expands the `$(error …)` and the build stops.

As a refinement, 
if `${INCLUDES}` can expand to more than one folder (as implied by its name),
then you should test each path individually.

```
mustexist = $(or $(realpath $1),$(error Path [$1] does not exist!))
includes = $(foreach _,$1,-I$(call mustexist,$_))

1.o: 1.cpp
    gcc $(call includes,${INCLUDES}) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Below suggestion is the straightforward approach to add one folder.

Try like this, this should solve your problem.

```
INCLUDES:=/home/ecee/C1M1-Abubaker/include/common
<compiler and your source files> -I../$(realpath $(INCLUDES))
```

Comment: This is dodgy on a number of levels! If `$INCLUDES` is more than one folder, you need the `-I` pre-pended to _all_ of them. Worse than that, `$(realpath …)` can expand to nothing, leaving you with `-I/`, which is wrong.

Comment: @bobbogo, it 's just an example. I didn't paid attention to the number of levels. I will change that. Now, I read the OP question, he is not including more than one folder.

Comment: The collapse to `-I/` if the folder does not exist is arguably the worse problem though.